# Bash make and open directory

Tags: bash, command-line

Let's say I have the following command:

```
mkdir directory && cd directory
```

I normally do this a lot during the day so I'm wondering if there is a simpler shorter way of doing this.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call last argument by `&_`

```
mkdir directory && cd $_
```

this is result

```
system:/tmp # mkdir directory && cd $_
system:/tmp/directory #
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` :

```
  mkcd () {
      mkdir "$1"
      cd "$1"
    }
```

Then in your shell, enter the following command `mkcd foo`. As you can see, this function need one argument which are the name of the directory.